# How to prove that $m < n \Longleftrightarrow m + 1 < n + 1$ when defining natural numbers from scratch in ZFC?

Tags: induction, set-theory, natural-numbers

An important results for natural numbers and their ordering by $<$ (that is, $\in$, $m < n$ means $m \in n$) is that for any natural numbers $m,n$ and $k$, we have $m < n \Longleftrightarrow m + 1 < n + 1$.

What preliminary results are needed? This is also a preliminary result, a lemma for the following result by induction: $\forall m,n,k \in \mathbb{N}, m < n \Longleftrightarrow m + k < n + k$.

Mathematical induction is assumed, of course, as is the fact that $m + 1 = m\cup\{m\}$. Also, it has already been proven that $\leq$ ($m \leq n$ stands for $m < n$ or $m = n$) is a well-ordering on $\mathbb{N}$. The addition is defined as follows: $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$,

- $m + 0 = m$,
- $m + (n + 1) = (m + n) + 1$.

Comment: $m + 1 = m\cup\{m\}$ is just one way to _construct_ a set behaving like the natural numbers; the actual construction used should be of no consequence in an argument using the axioms. Once you've shown that your construction indeed fulfills the axioms, of course.

Comment: @Arthur: Depending on how you do things, you might want to argue that directly. And while it is true that the finite von Neumann ordinals is just one of many ways of doing this, it is also the standard way of constructing the natural numbers in set theory. So standard to the point that many people out side of set theory would consider it "the way of doing it" (which often has sour implications on the view people have on set theoretic foundations later in their life).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if $m+1<n+1$, then $m\cup\{m\}\in n\cup\{n\}$, therefore either $m\cup\{m\}=n$, in which case $m\in n$ and we are done, or $m\cup\{m\}\in n$, in which case $m\in n$ and we are done again.

Secondly, if $m\in n$, then either $m\cup\{m\}\in n$, in which case we are clearly done; or $m\cup\{m\}=n$, in which case $n\in n\cup\{n\}$ so $m\cup\{m\}\in n\cup\{n\}$.

---

What did we use? We used the fact that $n$ is transitive, so $x\in y\in n$ means $x\in n$. It is tempting that we directly appeal to the fact that $\in$ is well-founded, and therefore there are no $\in$-loops, but it doesn't matter. If they were are $\in$-loops in that definition it would just show that $<$ is not a linear ordering (or a partial ordering for that matter), the proof would still work.

Comment: Thank you, Asaf. Trying by myself, I managed to do one side of the equivalence, namely the first one in your answer. As for the second one, from what I can see, there is an additional lemma required: for any natural numbers $m$ and $n$, $n < m$ implies $n + 1 \leq m$.

Comment: Hmm. It might be needed to have that $\in$ is in fact well-founded (from which you can easily derive that $n+1\leq m$).

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to use the axiom of foundation. In fact, we could use the result that $\leq$ is a total order on $\mathbb{N}$: assume that $n < m$. As $\mathbb{N}$ is totally ordered by $\leq$, then we have $n + 1 \leq m$ or $m < n + 1$. The latter implies that either $m = n$ or $m < n$, contradicting $n < m$ due to transitive and irreflexive nature of $<$ as a strict order with respect to total order $\leq$ on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Oh, I meant that $\in$ is well-founded on the natural numbers. If you already have that this is a total order, then it's even easier.